# Defining Sequelize Models for PostgreSQL Custom Type

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use Sequelize to add products to my postgresql database. I'm having a bit difficulty in figuring out how to include the custom data type 'product' as an array in my table model definition.

Model Definitions:

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
  product_category: Sequelize.TEXT,
  product_id: Sequelize.TEXT,
  product_name: Sequelize.TEXT,
  product_image: Sequelize.TEXT,
});

const Orders = sequelize.define('orders', {
  order_id: Sequelize.TEXT,
  products: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.Product),
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
});
```

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id text PRIMARY KEY,
  products product[]
);
```

My custom type definition:

```
CREATE TYPE product AS (
  product_category TEXT,
  product_id TEXT,
  product_name TEXT,
  product_image TEXT
);
```